# Conditions on a DF or Series.?

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements, series

Hi I imported a dataset called `train` and selected `"Sex"` from this list.

But I couldn't use the `if` statement on it. I get the following error :

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I have already tried changing it to string datatype but without result.

What can i do to fix this? Changing it to a DF doesnt help same error.

```
import numpy as np



Sex = train['Sex']


for x in Sex : 
    if Sex == "male" :
        SurvBi = 0
    else :
        SurBi = 1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Comment: it should be rather `x == "male"`.

Comment: what do you want to check - `male` in every row separatelly, or globally `male` for column? First may need to keep all results in list, second doesn't need `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> this solution may help

```
import pandas as pd

train = {
  "Sex": ["male","female"],
}
Sex = train['Sex']
for x in Sex:

    SurvBi = 0 if x == "male" else 1
    print(SurvBi)
```

Answer (score 0):

Note to always check your formatting before posting your question so people have more time to solve your problem than to reconstruct your problem.

Assuming you know how to create a pandas DataFrame out of your data, this approach will work.

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if row == "male":
        SurvBi = 0
    elif row == "female":
        SurBi = 1
    else: 
        print("invalid")
```

Comment: No, copied pasted still same error.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to check value for every row separatelly then you should use `x == 'male'`

```
for x in train.Sex: 
    if x == "male":
        SurBi = 0
    else:
        SurBi = 1
    print(x, SurBi)
```

or you can use fact that `int(True)` gives `1`, and `int(False)` gives `0`

```
for x in train.Sex:
    SurBi = int(x != "male")
    print(x, SurBi)
```

But if you want to use all results later then you should keep them on list

```
all_results = [] 

for x in train.Sex: 
    if x == "male":
        SurBi = 0
    else:
        SurBi = 1
    print(x, SurBi)
    all_results.append( SurBi )
```

but it would be simpler to do

```
all_results = (train.Sex != "male").astype(int).to_list()
```

---

But if you want to check for all column at once then you have to remember that `panda` (and `numpy`) works on vector/matrix and comparition gives also vector/matrix like `[True, False, ...]` but `if` needs single result `True` or `False` - and you have to use `any( Sex == "male" )` or `all( Sex == "male" )` to get single value

```
if any( Sex == "male" ):
   print('At least one person is male')

if all( Sex == "male" ):
   print('All persons are male')
```